# wildfly 10 unexpected shutdown often

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssh, wildfly, putty, wildfly-10

Currently i have issue.
application server (wildfly 10) unexpected shutdown often.

so i have check the server log nothing is there about the shutdown.

application running in aws(amazon web services).

application server name -wildfly 10.

am using putty to start the application(remote session) 
server start command **/usr/share/wildfly/bin/standalone.sh &**

once i start i will close the putty.
i have place *&* symbol in start command so it will run in background, but after few days it's **unexpected shutdown** and nothing is there in **server log**.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

When you start applications from a command line on any unix based OS, it will be terminated automatically when the terminal session is closed, unless you tell the OS not to do that:

```
some-aws-prompt$ nohup /usr/share/wildfly/bin/standalone.sh &
```

The `nohup` command is an abbreviation for "don't hang up (the phone)" or "no hang up" when the user logs out.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
currently in my case system having memory issue so OOM killer has killed my Process.